# ASP.NET error sending mail

Tags: asp.net, sendmail

This is intranet application and I am using company's mail realy to send emails. It works fine in other applications I have but not in this one and everything is the same.
I get "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Syntax error in parameters or arguments. The server response was: 5.5.2 MAIL FROM syntax error" when attempting to send mail.
This is how I set it up:

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
    mm.From = new MailAddress("NoReply@AMS_Redirection.company.org");
    mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("my_emailaddress@company.org"));
    mm.Subject = "AMS Redirection Error";
    mm.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mm.Body = "some html stuff here";

    SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("mailrelay.company.org");
    sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential();

    try
    {
        sc.Send(mm);
    }
    catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
    {
        //A problem occurred when sending the email message
        string sScript = string.Format("alert(\"There was a problem in sending the email: {0}\");", smtpEx.Message.Replace("\r\n", " "));
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SMTP Error", sScript, true);
    }
```

I can successfully ping the mail relay.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the 'from' address to something you KNOW is wrong. I get this exception when the 'from' address is rejected by my SMTP forwarding service. If it still fails the same way you know the problem is in the config of the relay.

Answer (score 0):

did you check if the smtp port of your SMTP server is the standard port? Otherwise you have to explicitly set it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies,Enrico and @n8wrl. I tested this in another intranet application that uses the exact same code and they work fine. So, I am not sure if it is the mail realy issue. The "From:" is a fake email address just to let the user know not to respond it and set the same way in other apps.

Comment: @n8wrk and Enrico, I found the issue and it seems really childish; I don't know if this is for all email addressess or it is just our mail relay but when I changed the "From:" address from AMS_Redirection.company.org to AMSRedir.company.org it worked fine. I got rid of underscore and shortened a bit!!